# Getting a nullpointerexception error when trying to draw to canvas

Tags: java

I'm trying to paint essentially a checkerboard pattern to the screen by using a 2d array and painting 10x10 pixel blocks at the current coordinate based on what character is read from the array location. I think this is all the code related to the problem:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        for(int x = 0;x<=3;x++){
            for(int y = 0;y<=3;y++){
                                // NPE occurs on this line:
                if (globalmap[x][y] == '1'){g2d.fillRect(10*y, 10*x, 10,10);}
            }
        }
}
```

This is the map array:

```
0000
0011
0100
0000
```

Stack trace:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.side.side.GameEngine.paint(GameEngine.java:64)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 64:

```
if (globalmap[x][y] == '1') { g2d.fillRect(10*y, 10*x, 10,10); }
```

Comment: ... Which line is line 64?

Comment: Are you sure that globalmap is not null?

Comment: Seriously, what's line 64? You know we can't see your monitor, right?

Comment: So which is `null`, `globalmap` or `g2d`? I'm with narek. Have you considered using the debugger?

Comment: Can you post how you have defined and initialized the globalmap?

Comment: Not your problem, but custom painting should be done by overriding the paintComponent() method NOT the paint() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your globalmap array elements are null, but it's hard to tell based on what you're posting.  Note that this line is terrible:

```
 if (globalmap[x][y] == '1'){g2d.fillRect(10*y, 10*x, 10,10);}
```

You need to spread this out on several lines if only for debugging purposes:

```
if (globalmap[x][y] == '1') {
    g2d.fillRect(10*y, 10*x, 10,10);
}
```

Comment: Turns out the function that assigns values to global map never executed. Thank you very much for pointing this out to me in addition to helping with my bad practice.

Comment: @purpleladydragons: aha, glad you've got it working. For this type of problems, I sometimes add println statements above the line throwing the NPE to see what is wrong, something like `System.out.println("globalmap is null: " + (globalmap == null));` and  `System.out.println("globalmap[x][y] is null: " + (globalmap[x][y] == null));`, etc... This is why println is sometimes called, "the poor man's debugger". You also could use the debugging feature of most IDEs.